# DART lang, working with list of Map, how?

Tags: dart

I'e a sales order of many lines, want to handle each line as a Map of (number, Item code, Qty), and need to have all these maps in list, so that orderlines[0] is the Map of the first order line.

If I've 3 lines, then the below worked very well.

But what if I do not know the number of lines, and it depend on the user, then how can define it!

```dart
  var orderLines = [{ 'number'  : '',
                  'Item' : '',
                  'Qty'  : ''
                 },
                 { 'number'  : '',
                  'Item' : '',
                  'Qty'  : ''
                 },
                 { 'number'  : '',
                  'Item' : '',
                  'Qty'  : ''
                 }
               ];
```

I need to define the "orderLines" so I can get it filled by the data in the below code:

```dart
   for(int i=0;i<=number_of_lines;i++){
       orderLines[i]['number']=element.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].value;
       orderLines[i]['number']=element.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].value;
       orderLines[i]['Qty']=element.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].value;  
 }
```

Comment: can to answer this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55216624/11065582

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Update according to the updated question

You can't assign a value to a List at a specific index if the list is shorter than the index.
You have to fill the list using `add`. If the list already has a value at a given index you can replace the value by `mylist[someIndex] = someValue;`

```dart
var orderLines = <Map>[]; // creates an empty List<Map>

for(int i=0; i <= number_of_lines; i++){
  var map = {};
  map['number'] = element.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].value;
  map['Item'] = element.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].value;
  map['Qty'] = element.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].value; 
  orderLines.add(map);
}
```

or

```dart
for(int i = 0; i <= number_of_lines; i++){
  orderLines.add({
    'number': element.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].value,
    'Item': element.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].value,
    'Qty': element.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].value});
}
```

#### Original answer

I'm not sure what you want to know but I suppose this is what you are looking for

```dart
var orderLines = <Map>[]; // creates an empty List<Map>

orderLines.add({ 'number'  : '',
              'Item' : '',
              'Qty'  : ''
             });
orderLines.add({ 'number'  : '',
              'Item' : '',
              'Qty'  : ''
             });
orderLines.add({ 'number'  : '',
              'Item' : '',
              'Qty'  : ''
             });
```

Comment: thanks, 3 options worked correctly :) personally prefer the last option   orderLines.add({
    'number': element.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].value, ...}

Answer (score 3):

You can also reconsider using own class instead of map.

```dart
class OrderLine{
  String number;
  String item;
  String qty;

  OrderLine.fromElement(Element element){
    number = element.childNodes[0].value;
    /// ...
}}

for(Element element in elements){
    orderLines.add(new OrderLine.fromElement(element.childNodes[i]));
}
```

This solution makes your code more maintable. You can fully put typecheck to use (number will probably not be typed as String). You can use autocomplete.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous answer and created a new one instead just updating your first answer?

Comment: Stack overflow foces me to edit answer in separate window, so I cannot read the question. I pushed tab key to indent and enter to make new line. It sends the first answer.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by `forces you to edit answer in separate window`. For me there is no difference whether I create a new answer or edit an existing one. To you it probably looks as it doesn't make any difference but I suppose you still see the deleted answer yourself and others with higher reputation also still see it. I just try to help maintain the quality of questions/answers and wondered what caused your decision and whether I can help to avoid this in the future.

Comment: If I click edit button, I'm redirected to new page, where is only main template, preview of answer and edit text area. There isn't original question. I've forgot OrderLine properties, so I've returned back with content copy in the system box. Faster solution, than two tabs in browser was to delete first answer and create new one.

Comment: May I ask which browser do you use? When I click edit the answer just changes to an edit field with the preview below.

Comment: Chrome Verze 37.0.2062.103 m

Comment: @ZdeněkMlčoch: sorry for the confusion there; as a <2k user you don't inline edit. *However*, when you edit your post, you can still see the question; there is a grey bar *above* the editor, drag that down to see the whole question. *Don't repost*, just edit your answer please.

Comment: @ZdeněkMlčoch: I nedd to it in Map, as next step is decoding the data into json, and sending it to the server, can the class be decoded in the same way of the Map?

Comment: You can use mirrors, but I don't suggest this way. I am using class based solution and manualy typed toJson method. I'm working on a large application. Every hidden error is very expensive for me, more expensive than performance lost by transition and checking. (Testing could help in your solution, but it is another discussion.).